# Visual Studio 2013 Community Installer installed the Express Edition

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Recently, I decided to "get with the times" and upgrade from VS2012 to VS2013. I downloaded the installer, and ran it. The first time around, the install failed around the 80th component, but I tried again and it worked. When it finished, I booted up VS, and it all looked fine, save for that little word on the splash screen, "express". I didn't really care for a while, but now I need a GLSL plugin, and it won't install, on account of it being the express edition. I would prefer not to reinstall, as it took quite a while last time, and I'm not too confident in the installers ability to not muck up my projects.

Comment: Apparently this was downvoted. Maybe this is ill-advised, but I would like to know why, because I genuinely can't see the issue with this question. When you google the problem, the first result is this very question.

Comment: Do a reinstall. If needed run the setup once with `/uninstall /force` to make sure you have a clean start.

Comment: Ok, your reinstall idea worked. Thanks for helping when apparently no one else would. I suppose 2 downvotes is the price I pay for my laziness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever Visual Studio installations end up in a funny state, it's best to try to reinstall it. Most of the times just running setup again and choosing Repair will do the trick, but sometimes your configuration is corrupted in such a way that it prevents repairs. In that case try running setup with the `/uninstall /force` command line options once to forcefully evict Visual Studio from your computer before trying the installation again.

It may feel that it's faster to try and 'fix' Visual Studio, but remember that this is a massive beast installing and configuring many different packages and components and trying to manually ensure that they're all correct is incredibly hard. It may seem that you fixed it, but then later find out that the debuggger acts funny or that you can't create a certain type of project.

So, to prevent those strange issues, always, in case of a failed install, sit through it once more.